# Map static field between nutch and solr

Tags: static, solr, field, nutch

I use nutch 1.4 and I would like to map static field to Solr.

I know there is the index-static plugin. I configured it in nutch-site.xml like this :

```
    <property>
        <name>index-static</name>
        <value>field:value</value>
    </property>
```

However, the value is not sent to Solr.

Does anyone have a solution ?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the entry in nutch-default.xml is wrong.
According to the plugin source "index.static" instead of "index-static" is the right name for the property.

```
String fieldsString = conf.get("index.static", null);
```

After using that in my nutch-site.xml I was able to send multiple fields to my solr server.

Also make sure that the plugin is added to list of included plugins in the "plugin.includes" property.